# Is it possible to display the DataView Webpart in datasheet view?

Tags: data-view-web-part, datasheet

Is it possible to display the DataView Webpart in datasheet view?

Answer (score 0):

No as the name itself suggest DATAVIEW is used to provide formatted view of the data.

For data sheet view: Create your desired datasheet view in the list, go to your web part page and add the list web part and change the view to use the datasheet view.